# For $T: X \to Y$ with Hilbert $X,Y$, show that if $T^* Tx = T^*y$ then $x$ minimizes ${\lVert Tx - y \rVert}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> For $T: X \to Y$ with Hilbert $X,Y$, show that if $T^* Tx = T^*y$ then $x$ minimizes ${\lVert Tx - y \rVert}$

By hypothesis $T^* Tx = T^* y$, so $T^*(Tx - y) = 0$, so $Tx - y \in \mathop{\text{null}} T^*$. There is a proposition that says $\mathop{\text{null}} T^* = (\mathop{\text{im}} T)^\perp$ so $Tx - y \in \mathop{\text{null}} T^* = (\mathop{\text{im}} T)^\perp$. If $\mathop{\text{im}} T$ is closed then there is a proposition that says $Tx$ minimizes ${\lVert Tx-y \rVert}$ and completes the proposition but we can't make that assumption. I'm stuck on this proof when we can't assume that $\mathop{\text{im}} T$ is closed.

One more useful piece:

Let $M := \overline{\mathop{\text{im}} T} \subset Y$. For each $y \in Y$, a textbook proposition says that there exists a unique $y_* \in M$ that minimizes ${\lVert y - y_* \rVert}$ such that

\begin{align*}
  \forall m \in M, {\lVert y - y_* \rVert} \le {\lVert y - m \rVert} \\
\end{align*}

Another proposition says $y - y_* \in M^\perp$. Since $\mathop{\text{im}} T \subset M$ then $M^\perp \subset (\mathop{\text{im}} T)^\perp$ and another proposition says $\mathop{\text{nullspace}} T^* = (\mathop{\text{im}} T)^\perp$ so:

\begin{gather*}
  y - y_* \in M^\perp \subset (\mathop{\text{im}} T)^\perp = \mathop{\text{null}} T^* \\
  T^*(y - y_*) = 0 \\
  T^*y = T^* y_* \\
\end{gather*}

We can combine this with the hypothesis to get $T^* Tx = T^*y = T^* y_*$ such that $Tx - y_* \in \mathop{\text{null}} T^* = (\mathop{\text{im}} T)^{\perp}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
 \|Tz-y\|^2&=\|T(z-x)+Tx-y\|^2 \\
&=\|Tx-y\|^2+\|T(z-x)\|^2+2\langle T(z-x),Tx-y\rangle \\
&=\|Tx-y\|^2+\|T(z-x)\|^2 \\
&\geq \|Tx-y\|^2
\end{align*}
for all $z$.

Comment: thank you! simple, easy to follow, perfect!